# How to manage master data in memory to avoid harming database in n-layered application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework-6, software-design

I'm developing a desktop application for learning purposes and I'm dealing with uncertainty of how to **avoid damaging the database continuously querying for master data** every time user opens a form (window, user control, view, whatever) and **bad user experience by loading time**.

For example:
To create a new product, the application must load all categories and brands.
In general, this happens with all the data in the master tables (customers, employees, product categories, etc.).

The simplest solution for me:
Due to the nature of this type of data, I can **have a collections** that:
- **Query since the last update timespan when need it for new data.**
- **Update all the content of the collections every X time (maybe 1 hour).**

If this is the best solution, **where should i have these collections?**
I use 3 layers, DAL, BLL, PL where PL knows BLL.
Should these collections be static? Or be within a singleton class?

**Extra:**
I have tried to be as general as possible (without mentioning languages or frameworks).
However, I use C # and MySQL.
I was writing the program without `DataTable`s (just mapping the data obtained with `Command.ExecuteReader()` to my entities).
I recently made a copy and started working with EntityFramework 6.
I thought there might be a way to get EF to cache the results, but for this you need to implement a second level cache and I do not want to go that way (because my needs are simpler given the nature of the data).

**Thanks and sorry if my English is not good at all!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how do you store the master data values in in-memory but the logic wise it should go as following.

The BLL should first look for master data in `in-memory` and if found there then use that data.

If data is not available in `in-memory` then it should request that data from the DAL. DAL will pull the data from the database without worrying about the last updated date and send it back to BLL.

Now BLL should first store the data coming from DAL in `in-memory` with certain expiration duration and then use the data. The expiration duration will make sure that, when the expiration period is over the data is removed from the `in-memory` automatically.

And the cycle repeats.

The best way to store the data in `in-memory` is a collection such as List. So that you can iterate it thru easily and access properties of it easily.

Ideally if you have repository layer then Repository layer should take care of these things. BLL layer only call Repository for the master data and repository would worry about checking in the `in-memory` and getting from the Db if not available in `in-memory` and storing it back to `in-memory` with expiration.

Comment: Sorry, it was just something poorly written, the collections live in the memory. While writing, I thought of other options and it seems that I forgot to delete that.

Comment: So you are looking for some other way to storing the master data so that you don't need to query them from the database again and again? Correct me if I am wrong? Does the logic I explained makes sense ?

Comment: I use repositories, for some reason I didn't think of handling things there. Managing the data in the repositories... Should I make the collections static? Then the method must be static so that it can update the list?
And yes, you're right, that's what I need.

Comment: Making static is not required. That way you will lose the purpose of DI. Let that be part of instance methods of repository. No harm in that. If you want you can create separate repository only for master data and handle caching over there. Since this is a windows application creating static collections also not a problem though. But my suggestion would be to go Object Oriented way.

Comment: But some class has to be static or singleton, right?. Otherwise, how do I keep the data? I don't have any singleton or static class and I can't instantiate a repository in the presentation layer. The repositories are instanciated after UoW, so the data will be lost when the UoW instance is destroyed.

Comment: I'm afraid my question was general and my current doubts are more specific. Your answer in my opinion is correct (for my original question). I'll wait until tomorrow anyway to mark it as the solution. However, I'm very new to this and if you could help me with the new doubts I have, I would greatly appreciate it, otherwise thank you anyway :D

Comment: Singleton would be helpful here. Presentation layer should depend on BLL for any data rather than repository. So you need to make one class in BLL a singleton for master data. But the main logic will revolve around when to refresh the data from db to `in-memory`. So the Singleton object should make sure that it keeps data in `in-memory` and refreshes it when needed while it is alive during the application life cycle.